# Why is my 2004 BMW z4 front suspension making noise?

Tags: suspension, bmw

Every time I go into rough terrain, specifically bumps or speed bumps, there is a thud sound from the front end. Thinking it might be the bushings but I'd prefer not to purchase without confirmation.

Comment: When was the alignment last done?

Comment: Also, have the shocks been replaced recently?

Comment: YouTube "BMW Control arm bushes E46 or Z4 / Z3 How to DIY: BMTroubleU"

Answer (score 1):

Knocking and squeaking on the Beamers front end usually ends up at the 'bottom-arm rear-bushes'. Check the bushing for excessive movement.

A bottom arm bush failure can be diagnosed on the road by a quick 'stab' of the brakes whilst driving the vehicle. There will be a thud through the steering.

Before stabbing the brakes on the road, make sure the traffic, if any, is not too close!

EDIT - YouTube Video: [BMW Control arm bushes E46 or Z4 / Z3 How to DIY: BMTroubleU](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENJQpe50WBg)

Comment: What is meant by "excessive movement"? How do you check for this on this vehicle? Where is this bushing located exactly? Do you have a picture of this or a link which would show exactly what you are talking about?

Comment: BMW Control arm bushes E46 or Z4 / Z3 How to DIY: BMTroubleU.